# Passing an array of strings to UITableView headers

Tags: swift

I am having trouble passing an `Array<String>` or `[String]` to the UITableView headers section name.

```
UITableHeaders = [
    "Current Part Number",
    "Work Center",
    "Cycle Time",
    "Current Part Cycle Time",
    "Parts Made",
    "Cycle Time Actual",
    "Target",
    "Downtime",
    "Status Reason",
    "Line Status",
    "Production Effeciency",
    "Plus Minus (From Target)",
    "Current Production Time"
]
```

---

**First try:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let titlesForHeadersArray: [String] = varStorage().UITableHeaders
    let titlesCount = titlesForHeadersArray.count

    return titlesForHeadersArray[]
}
```

**Second try:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let titlesForHeadersArray: [String] = varStorage().UITableHeaders
    let titlesCount = titlesForHeadersArray.count

    return titlesForHeadersArray[0...titlesCount]
}
```

These two are my two attempts at trying to fill the headers with the array values I have stored. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`Error: Ambiguous subscript with base type '[String]' and index type 'ClosedRange<Int>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to **section** in **titleForHeaderInSection**

> `titleForHeaderInSection` Asks the data source for the title of the header of the specified section of the table view.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let titlesForHeadersArray: [String] = varStorage().uiTableHeaders

    return titlesForHeadersArray[section]
}
```

and your **numberOfSection** should be return your array **count**

> `numberOfSections` Asks the data source to return the number of sections in the table view.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return varStorage().uiTableHeaders.count
}
```

Comment: @HRD1997BFBE Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Function **TitleForHeaderInSection** waits, that you return String, while you try to return array of strings.
Try to change **return titlesForHeadersArray[0...titlesCount]** to **return titlesForHeadersArray[section]**